# What to use for a page approval sharepoint online - classic

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page, approval-process, content-approval

I have requirement to have an approval built for pages.

I know there is an approval page built in flow/power automate but this needs to be for classic SharePoint sites.

Any idea?

Can I use SharePoint Designer workflow?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site Pages and Pages library are basically Document libraries in SharePoint. So, Like any other document libraries you can enable content approval for these libraries as well.

You can use SharePoint OOTB Content Approval for such scenario's. To enable content approval follow below steps:

1. Go to Library Settings
2. Select Versioning Settings
3. Select "Yes" for "Require content approval for submitted items?"
4. Click OK

[image]

You can also use SharePoint designer workflows to manage content approval for these libraries/Pages.

**Reference**:

[Require approval of items in a site list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08)